# mysql-server fails to install after previous failure (and start, and thus configure)

Tags: mysql

Ubuntu 14.10 64bit

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-common && sudo rm -r /etc/mysql
```

Now that we are uninstalled

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  nginx-common nginx-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1763 kB of archives.
After this operation, 33.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...

Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                               Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Nmap shows the port isn't in use:
`nmap localhost`

```
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
631/tcp   open  ipp
5800/tcp  open  vnc-http
5900/tcp  open  vnc
30000/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

And mysql log is this.

```
sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

150216 18:04:18 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150216 18:04:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size
InnoDB: 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
InnoDB: initial 640 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
150216 18:04:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150216 18:04:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150216 18:04:18 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150216 18:04:18 [ERROR] Aborting

150216 18:04:18 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The first time I ran `tasksel` and installed the LAMP Server, i ran out of disk space during the install. That is *very likely* related.

Comment: Are you concerned with preserving any existing databases? if not, you might want to try removing the data files in /var/lib/mysql (which should include the ibdata1 file), not only the configuration files at /etc/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned, it's recommended you have at least 1GB of space free on / in order to have a working system, as for mysql try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Probably your apt cache is old and it's trying to pull some bad package config. I see that now mysql-server is meta package for mysql-server-5.6

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can. Now it won't even load grub. It's a SeaBIOS on a chrubuntu Chromebook (I've wiped the Chrome OS) and unfortunately, when I rebooted last, it just stalls in SeaBIOS with no errors, but can't load the grub bootloader. =/

Comment: Humble suggestion, don't run anything write intensive on solid state devices, especially not something write intensive as mysql. It will kill your SSD faster than expected, and since it's an appliance, there's high chance you can't replace it either. As for the chromebook, I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with their boot sequence.

Comment: MySQL is only write intensive during operation right? I'm just using for localhost to test a PHP app. I hope it doesn't write all the time

Comment: It's more than that.. it builds caches, and indexes and precompiled queries. It updates timestamps on tables ( depending on what you use it for). On inserts indexes are rebuilt, caches regenerated. Just that if you insert a row, it doesn't necessarily mean that MySQL does just that. It might do ten times more writes in the name of performance. Another thing to think on. Have you made sure your partition is solidstate optimized mounted? options such as noatime,nodiratime,discard no swap on ssd?

Comment: Taking a better look on your logs, seems you run out of space..
You have to have at least 1Gb free on / not to have problems
`InnoDB: 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
InnoDB: initial 640 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
150216 18:04:18 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.`

on / which is bad.. You need a rescue disk/ mode to open your / and remove  stuff from it. /var/logs/* you can remove all of it, since it's only logs. You could also remove your website from /var/www . You could also

Comment: Once you freed some space on / then you can try rebooting normally. There's a high chance it will start as expected.

Comment: `relatime` is now standard in modern unix, which means that it's SSD optimized by default.